# HTML Performance Improvements using append

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Based on the code below, I would like to know if there would be a significant change in the page loading time if i would to call the desktopPopup html scripts later (assuming I have alot of html codes which are being executed there) or am I doing it just wrong? The comparison is using the method below and against writing the entire html code without the scripts

```
 <script id="desktop" type="text/html">
        //some html in here
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('body').one("click", function(e) {
      $("body").append($('#desktop').html());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: physical loading time is the same since the same data is transfered in the script tag as in a normal html tag. render time is longer since ready() breaks up the layout, causing additional paint events and script run time delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including it right away will be faster. In this case your browsers only needs to build DOM and render it.

In the second case your browser has to:

- download and execute jQuery (if it hasn't been done beforehand)
- select elements from DOM, insert HTML into it
- rebuild part of DOM and render it